# How to get horizontal camera when running a macOS app designed for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipad, swiftui

I built a simple camera app using SwiftUI for macOS. Originally, I ran my code on my mac using Mac Catalyst, and it ran fine:
[image: Run on Mac Catalyst]

```
class Camera: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: CIImage?

    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?

    func setUpAndStartCamera() {
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            return
        }
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .high

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "random", attributes: [])
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
                videoOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait
            }
            self.captureSession = captureSession
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        }
        catch {
            print("Error starting camera session: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a SwiftUI view that just displays the image from this camera. I recently came upon a framework that doesn't run on Mac Catalyst, so I need to run the app on My Mac designed for iPad. However, when I run the exact same code on that destination: the camera becomes vertical like an iPad camera:
[image: Run on iPad design]

Is there any way to get the standard horizontal camera when running on a macOS app designed for iPad? I've tried changing the `videoOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you find a working solution? I'm getting the video rotated

Comment: I didn't unfortunately

Comment: Long time, since posting and no answer. It must be a catalyst thing? I am also struggling with this one too